# iphone sdk see size of local file (one created by application)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, file, nsarray, nsdata

Is there anyway I can look at the size of a file the application creates in bytes then store that number to use later?  OR is there any way I can tell if an object in an NSArray is empty, I've tried everything, but it just doesn't work!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use NSFileManager class' method

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

The size key in the returned dictionary is defined as

```
NSString * const NSFileSize;
```

So for an example

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
    attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/path/to/file" error:&error];

if (!error) {
    NSNumber *size = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
}
```

Comment: nduplessis it works well.But a small doubt when the file was in documents directory its size was 32 mb but when i transferred the file to ftp successfully the same file size was 38 mb.How's it possible? FYI: FTP is in 2003 server which is 64 bit system.