# NSFileManager filesize Incorrect for .xcodeproj File

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

From the Mac Finder app I know that my file PicViewer.xcodeproj has a files size of 35,697 bytes. The code below gives me a file size of 160. I know the code works as it correctly tells me the file size of an Excel file.

I used the code from this stackoverflow question [How can i get my file size in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743085/how-can-i-get-my-file-size-in-objective-c) with a minor change.

```
NSString *directoryPath = [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *array = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: directoryPath error:NULL];
for (NSString *filename in array) {
    NSError *attributesError = nil;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]
                                                    error:&attributesError];
    unsigned long long size = [attributes fileSize];
    NSString *filetype = [attributes fileType];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %llu", filename, filetype, size);
}
```

It also reports that the file type is NSFileTypeDirectory and not NSFileTypeRegular (and I suspect this is causing the file size to be reported incorrectly). For example:

Exercise Record.xlsx NSFileTypeRegular 637131

PicViewer.xcodeproj NSFileTypeDirectory 160

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xcodeproj` is a directory indeed, you can expand its contents in Finder using `Show package content` (or whatever, I do not use English MacOS) menu command, so in you want to calculate its size, you should do it recursively, for instance like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189216/3004003)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Is there anyway to distinguish between folders and package directories?

Comment: @Keith I do not think so, it is really just an ordinary directory which mimics to a file having a file-like dot-separated extension and an according app association to handle this

Comment: getResourceValue:  forKey: NSURLIsPackageKey worked for me in being able to tell the difference between a regular folder and a "package" folder packages from regular folders.