# How to get file size of file from iPhone documents folder

Tags: iphone, ios, documents

I have in which i save video file in documents folder it works fine,but i want to get the file size of the saved file,I have searched but did not get result using NSfileManager,here is the code which i use for saving video.I want to get the file size and show it on UILabel.

thanks

```
       NSURL*videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

       NSLog(@"found a video");

       videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

       NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
      [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:SS"];
      NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
      NSDate* theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];



      NSString*myDate=[dateFormat stringFromDate:theDate];
      NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];



    NSString*test=@"test";


    NSString*testUser=[test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];



    videopath= [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4",documentsDirectory,testUser]] autorelease];

    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];
    NSLog(@"Successs:::: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
            NSLog(@"video path --> %@",videopath);

            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videopath];
    AVURLAsset *avUrl = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];
    CMTime time1 = [avUrl duration];
    int seconds = ceil(time1.value/time1.timescale);

    //  durationTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];

    //  insertTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];



    NSString*messageA=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have recorded video of duration of %d seconds  ",seconds];


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:messageA
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];



    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieURL];// url= give your url video here
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 5);//it will create the thumbnail after the 5 sec of video
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    thumbnailImageView.image=thumbnail;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this its help you

```
 NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:videopath traverseLink:YES];
     fileSize = [fileDictionary fileSize];
```

Comment: This file size will be KB or Bytes

Comment: this file size in bytes

Comment: fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink: is deprecated from iOS 6

Comment: you also use use attributesOfItemAtPath:error: method its also give the same result.

Comment: Method is deprecated. Go with - attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** Above Method is deprecated so, use below method

**Objective-C:**

```
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:mediaURL error: &error];
    NSNumber *size = [fileDictionary objectForKey:NSFileSize];
```

**Swift:**

```
do
{
   let fileDictionary = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: urlString)
   let fileSize = fileDictionary[FileAttributeKey.size]
   print ("\(fileSize)")
} 
catch{}
```

** **this file size in bytes**

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:

It returns an NSDictionary of file attributes and one key it contains is NSFileSize, the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
    // Get file size
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:[directoryContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager fileAttributesAtPath:filePath traverseLink:YES];
if(fileAttributes != nil)
{
NSString *fileSize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ kb", fileSize]];
NSLog(@"File size: %@ kb", fileSize);
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Before few days I was also searching for something very similar. I was needed to upload the local file to the dropbox and here is something that worked for me: Check the below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694928/2098401